# Group order or order element of a group G

Tags: group-theory

Prove that for a element $x \in G$ ($G$ is a group )

a) $x = x^{-1}$ if and only if order$(x) = 2$ or order$(x) = 1$ .

Answer (score 2):

If $x = x^{-1}$ then multiplying by $x$ gives either $x = e$, or $x^2 = e, x \neq e$ so $x$ has order $1$ or $2$. Conversely, if $x$ has order $1$ or $2$ then $x^2 = e$, now just multiply both sides by $x^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

The only element in a group $G$ with order 1 is the identity, $e$ which trivially satisfies the above. Suppose $x = x^{-1}$, $x \neq e$. Multiplying on the right by $x$, yields $x^2 = e$ and since $x \neq e$, the order of $x$ is 2.

Every step above is justified by invoking that $x$ is a element of a group.

The converse I will leave to you.